# 6 monitors in ubuntu 14.04 don't work in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, kde

```
Mother board: ASUS Z97-E
Memory      : 32GiB
CPU         : Intel i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
OS          : Ubuntu 14.04LTS Linux-x86_64
File System : ZFS on Linux on root
NVIDIA driver : 346.35
GPU (Two cards) : GeForce GT 740
Video Ports     : VGA,HDMI,VID per card, total 6 ports
Xserver version : 11.0
Monitors        : HannStar JC199D, 2xAcer AL1917, 3xASUS VS247;
Display Manager : KDE Plasma 4.xx
```

With this setup I am running 6 monitors using the DM above with no
problems whatsoever. I even boot with ZFS root.
Now, besides the difficulties of installing Ubuntu16.04.2 on root ZFS
on which I have given up temporarily, I install UBuntu16.04.2 on a whole
disk using ext4 file system.

**THE PROBLEM:** All display managers (gnome, unity, KDE) only can display
three monitors from one video card while the monitors in the second card
stay blank. PLEASE HELP